# form to submit to the user's email address

Tags: forms, email, submit

I am trying to create a question and answer style quiz on a website, using forms. I would like the submit button to email the user only, from a field he/she has previously filled in, but I can't figure out how. Also, advice on whether php is the best language to write this in?

I am very new to this and would really appreciate any help. Many thanks

Comment: can you post your current relevant code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

use the phpmailer function to send emails using php. You can read more about it [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsendmail) and get the library from github [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)